# href that links to a section within page not working, html

Tags: html, css, list, href, anchor

I'm on the process of making a vertical navbar with lists that links to a section of a page, and as I was testing if the lists of links I made directs me to its corresponding section, it seems to not work (I tried clicking the Brief Overview link and it's not directing me to the Brief Overview Section?) I've already double checked it and does not seem to find any problem or typos within the `section id` and the `a href`. But I may have missed something, please help me find out how this'll work.

```
<main id="main-doc">
  <div class="page-wrapper">
    <nav id="navbar">
      <header><h1>Python for Beginners</h2></header>
      <ul id="main-list">
        <li><a href="#Brief_Overview" class="nav-link">Brief Overview</a></li>
        <ul id="sub-list">
          <li><a href="#What-is-Python?" class="nav-link">What is Python?</a></li>
          <li><a href="#What-can-Python-do?" class="nav-link">What can Python do?</a></li>
           <li><a href="#Why-Python?" class="nav-link">Why Python?</a></li>
           <li><a href="#Python-compared-to-other-languages" class="nav-link">Python compared to other languages</a></li>
        </ul>  
      </ul>  
    </nav>  
  </div>  
  <section id="#Brief_Overview" class="main-section">
    <header><h2 class="Main-Header">Brief Overview</h2></header>
    <h3 class="Sub-Heading" id="#What-is-Python?">What is Python?</h3>
  </section>
  <section id="" class="main-section">
    <header><h2></h2></header>
  </section>
  
</main>
```

Comment: Please always use a [Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org) to check if you have a valid markup yourself. Multiple issues within your code: `<ul>` is not allowed to be a child of another `<ul>` tag. Missing opening tags, missing closing tags. ID's do not start with a `#` in HTML. `ID attribute` can not be empty.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `<section>` tag to

```
<section id="Brief_Overview" class="main-section">
```

Element identifiers don't include the `#` character, it's used only when targeting them through `href` or when querying the DOM with a *CSS selector*.